# Why does test.regex always returns true?

Tags: regex, vba

I have troubles using regex to test if a string is acceptable, and if not display a message. I have checked for tutorials, and found this one, but it always returns true, whether the string matches or not.

```
Function TestRegEx(regex As Object, testpattern As String, stringtotest As String) As Boolean
Dim regMatch As Object  ' MatchCollection 

With regex 
.Pattern = testpattern 
.MultiLine = False
End With

' match test string against regex string 
Set regMatch = regex.Execute(stringtotest) 
TestRegEx = (regMatch.Count > 0) 
End Function



Sub TestRegex() 
Dim regex As Object  ' RegExp 
Dim pattern As String
Dim inputstring As String

Set regex = GetRegEx 
If Not regex Is Nothing Then
testpattern = "[0-9]{1,3}" ' 1 to 3 numbers 
stringtotest = "12"
MsgBox TestRegEx(regex, pattern, inputstring) 
End If
End Sub
```

If i write something else into: stringtotest, like: baloon, dog, 3333 it always returns True.

```
testpattern = "^[0-9]{5}$" 
stringtotest = "KB"
```

Also returns: True

I tried to add

```
If TestRegEx(regex, pattern, inputstring) = True Then
msgbox "OK"
Else
msgbox "NotOK"
End IF
```

But it doesn't work, I always get OK.
What is wrong with the code?
How to fix it?

The same thing happens with my own code.

In my case, I need to check, if the subject of a mail in outlook contains a specific string. I use a slightly different code, then the tutorial, but it never gets False.

```
regex.pattern = "Cid#\d{4}"

If regex.Test(msg.Subject) = True Then
...
Else
...
```

**Edit**

```
Function GetRegEx() As Object
 On Error Resume Next
 Set GetRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
End Function
```

I forgot this, sorry.

And I've found this tutorial on a jpsoftware

**EDIT2: My code**

```
Dim objInsp As Outlook.Inspector
Dim msg As Outlook.MailItem
Dim regex As New RegExp
Dim prevsubj As String


Set objInsp = Application.ActiveInspector
Set msg = objInsp.CurrentItem
prevsubj = msg.Subject
subjlen = Len(prevsubj)


regex.IgnoreCase = False
regex.pattern = "Cid#\d{4}"
Set regex = GetRegEx


If regex.Test(msg.Subject) = True Then

MsgBox regex.Test(msg.Subject)


newtempsubj = Left(prevsubj, subjlen - 8)
msg.Subject = newtempsubj & " Cid#" & 'newidstring
msg.Close olSave
Else

MsgBox prevsubj

msg.Subject = prevsubj & " Cid#" & 'newidstring
msg.Close olSave

End If
```

Thanks in advance,
Z

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense.  `regex.Test` doesn't exist, and you're checking the return value from a `Sub`.?

Comment: `GetRegEx` what is this

Comment: I said my code is different, and in my code `regex.Test` exists. The first part is the complete tutorial, from which I wanted to understand these functions.

Comment: How are we going to help you if you don't give us the actual code and just give us some fictional alternative?

Comment: I want to know, why doesn't the tutorial works, so I can get a better understanding on this subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. I found it. One silly mistake - A typo.

You have one variable called `testpattern` and another called `pattern`.

`testpattern = "[0-9]{1,3}"` should be `pattern = "[0-9]{1,3}"` instead

similarly, you have `stringtotest` and `inputstring`. Change that as well

Comment: You are right!
I thought this tutorial would work the way it was, and couldn't figure it out. Now I will rewrite my own code according to this, because this works great.
Thank you.

Comment: To avoid the same mistake, I suggest developing a habit of declaring the variables before use. This can be enforced by adding `Option Explicit`